# A good instruction on Symmetry enriched Topological phases

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, topology, topological-field-theory, topological-order

I am looking for a good introduction to SETs, and topologically ordered phaeses it should be something describing first principles and gives a good explanation on the basics and the logic of this field. This can be mathematically rigours it won't be a problem, since I am fairly familiar with non interacting SPTs also FQHE, basics of QFT and RG.

There are a lot of papers, on SETs but I could not find any one that gives a basic and good introduction on the field, I don't need something too detailed or complete, I just want to understand the logic with mathematical rigor. Most of the papers, have several lines of comments on SETs than they start to calculate the specific problem they consider.

However, a paper or a chapter of book or a lecture note, that first defines topological order SETs and gives several different examples would be very good to teach me this two concepts. Most of the papers, around are not desinged to teach SET and Topological order.

Comment: Take a look at this link:https://topocondmat.org/